# Pentest Reporting

Tags: reporting

Hello i started doing pentesting for some customers, but i haven't been able to find any good software to assist in reporting. I've been doing these manually and formatting them manually, and its very tedious, i wanted to see if any other pentesters out there have any good recommendations on doing reporting.

I've tried dradis and serpico, but they don't seem to make nicely formatted reports like customers like.

EDIT: Any platform (windows or linux) is fine. Budget (Preferably open source, but if there is one that needs to be purchased, i would still be interested to know whats out there.)

Comment: Welcome. Do you have a budget in mind? And an operating system on which this app should run? The more info you give us, the better that we can help you, as explained in [ask]. I hope you get an answer, as this looks interesting :-) Perhaps you could tell us what information you want to report? And what format your data is in

Comment: Well i can either use linux or windows, depending on which software i can find and how good it works. I would like to use it for pentesting reports, so i can get outputs from nmap scans, nessus scans and webscans and would like to put that in nicely formatted report that i can give to executive or who ever needs to read the report.

Comment: It would be good if you  could update the question to say that. Most people will first reasd the question, and if they don't see any detail they might not bother

Comment: Any recommendations???

Comment: More info is needed about what you want your report to produce.  Would you want to insert the output from nmap as is or would you need to process it first (cut it down etc).  How would you get your info from nessus into the report - do you want screen shots?

Comment: Well i would like to import the data, so if i did an nmap scan, and it showed like 3 ports open and shows what services were running i would like to include that, also nessus which does vulnerability scanning, i would like to include those results as well